# How to Expand or "scale up" an 1d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math, decimation

I have a piece of C code that can only handle an array of size 20. The array that my instrument outputs is much smaller than what the function requires. Is there a numpy or math function that can "scale up" an array to any specific size while maintaining its structural integrity? For example:

I have a 8 element array that is basically a two ramp "sawtooth" meaning its values are :
[1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4]

What I need for the C code is a 20 element array. So I can scale it, by padding linear intervals of the original array with "0"s , like:

[1,0,0,2,0,0,3,0,0,4,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,3,0]

so it adds up to 20 elements. I would think this process is the opposite of "decimation". (I apologize ,I'm simplifying this process so it will be a bit more understandable)

Comment: Both answers were great , however i did not  have the "flaten" function. Thank you so much Derek and romain! Meaning there needs to be a "flaten" function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, I guess the following approach could be tweaked to do what you want:

1. upsample with 0s: `upsampled_l = [[i, 0, 0] for i in l]` with `l` being your initial list
2. Flatten the array `flat_l = flatten(upsampled_l)` using a method from
   [How to make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists) for instance
3. Get the expected length `final_l = flat_l[:20]`

For instance, the following code gives the output you gave in your example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
upsampled_l = [[i, 0, 0] for i in l]
flat_l = [item for sublist in upsampled_l for item in sublist]
final_l = flat_l[:20]
```

However, the final element of the initial list (the second 4) is missing from the final list. Perhaps it's worth upsampling with only one 0 in between (`[i, 0]` instead of `[i, 0, 0]`) and finally do `final_l.extend([0 for _ in range(20 - len(final_l))])`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can manage it in a one-liner by adding zeros as another axis, then flattening:

```py
sm = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4])
np.concatenate([np.reshape(sm, (8, 1)), np.zeros((8, 3))], axis=1).flatten()
```